# Using Rx from F# on portable class library has some problems still now?

Tags: f#, store, system.reactive, portability

Now I'm creating store app with pcl F# library and C# store project for 8.1.
OS is 8.1 Preview and VS is VS2013 Preview.

I tried to use Rx from pcl F# library.I could reference Rx assemblies which are in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Reactive Extensions\v2.0\Binaries.NETPortable\v4.5" successfully.

But I coudln't reference Rx classes from fs file.
F# compiler complained "The namespace 'Reactive' is not defined" for "open System.Reactive",why?

I have to do something another? or I can't?

Any advices will be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this with the latest stable Rx nuget package (2.1.30214), and VS 2013 RC on Win7, and it works.

Make sure your project type is "Portable Library" not "Portable Library (legacy)."  Only the former, which is new in VS 2013, supports targeting the .NET Framework profile that Rx uses.  The referenced version of FSharp.Core.dll should be 3.3.1.0.

[image: Rx and F#]

Comment: You're right!

I don't know why,but I believed I made FSharp portable library insted of FSharp portable library legacy...
I can reference Rx lib and it works fine.

Thanks!